# Incorrect runtime deserialization of enum in angular4/typescript with spring boot server

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

[server](https://github.com/mavriksc/enum-server)
[client](https://github.com/mavriksc/enum-test)

The issue is the server returns enum as string and the http client is allowed to set the member as a string at runtime. if i try in the code to set this.state = 'STATE_ONE' i get an error.it will also complain if i try to use the States[this.state]<-this should be the string representation.

relevant code:
typescript

```
enum States  {
    STATE_ONE,STATE_TWO,STATE_THREE
}

class IHaveStates {
   state: States;
   constructor(){}
}

sublist: States[]=[States['STATE_TWO'], States['STATE_THREE'] ];

getState(): Promise<IHaveStates> {
return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080')
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => response.json() as IHaveStates)
  .catch();
}

this.getState().then(thing => {
  let index = this.sublist.indexOf(thing.state);
  let statesICanCancel = index ===-1;

  console.log('State of the thing: '+thing.state);
  console.log('Enum value of State of the thing: '+States[thing.state]);     
  console.log('Sub list of can\'t cancel states: '+this.sublist);
  console.log('location cant cancel list: '+index);
  console.log('can i cancel: '+statesICanCancel);

});
```

if you run the code you see that when i set the state in code, when logged it will display the int value. When set from the service and logged it will be the string representation. meaning that if i try to do States[returnValue] and set that to a var of type State the compiler will complain rightfully thinking that is a string but in the service example will actually be int.

I'm able to resolve the issue by serializing the enum as integer server side.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue by instead of using indexOf() iterating thru and comparing values my self.

```
    canCancel(thing:IHaveStates):boolean{
    for (let state of this.sublist) {
      if (thing.state.toString() === States[state]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```